# Find the next number in the following sequence

Tags: number-sequence

It is easy when you get it. 
0,10,1110,3110,132110,?
Let me know if you already know about this.

Comment: Oh yes! Didn't know it was already there. Thanks. But still, this ones great!

Comment: When posting a `number-sequence` puzzle, always check [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001155) aswell.

Comment: FYI, this is known as the [look and say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence).